# why is gtk_show_uri trimming my url?

Tags: c, gtk

I am trying to recompile a gtk application and instead of launching the `g:help` browser, I want to launch the default browser and html file on my file system. 
I modified the source code to:

```
#define APP_HELP "file://usr/local/share/doc/APP/APP.html"

    /*ret = gtk_show_uri (gtk_widget_get_screen (GTK_WIDGET (parent)),
                        link, 
                GDK_CURRENT_TIME, 
                &error);*/
    ret = gtk_show_uri (gtk_widget_get_screen (GTK_WIDGET (parent)),
                        APP_HELP, 
                GDK_CURRENT_TIME, 
                &error);
```

But when I launch the help I see the following error:

[image]

What happened to `/usr` ? How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe is it because the URI should begin with `file:///usr/....`, the protocol part is `file://` follows the absolute path `/usr/...`

Comment: @Kwariz, yes thank you very much. The missing `/` solved it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the question after the useful remark from Kwariz:

```
because the URI should begin with file:///usr/....
```